# comma delimited list as a single string, T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My T-SQL query generates following result set

```
ID        Date
756 2011-08-29
756 2011-08-31
756 2011-09-01
756 2011-09-02
```

How can I convert like this

```
ID                Date
756 2011-08-29, 2011-08-31, 2011-09-01, 2011-09-02
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You could use `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF` to concatenate the multiple rows into a single row:

```
select distinct t1.id,
  STUFF(
         (SELECT ', ' + convert(varchar(10), t2.date, 120)
          FROM yourtable t2
          where t1.id = t2.id
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS date
from yourtable t1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0780d/1)

Comment: This gave me a starting space character. I fixed it by changing `, 1, 1, '')  AS date` to `, 1, 2, '')  AS date`.

Comment: This is neat, but it's tripping me up that the inner select somehow is referencing a variable (t1) from the outer select.  What is going on here?

Comment: @Michael - the column from the outer select is referenced in the inner basically as a cheap join. It's sort of like an EXISTS with a sub query.

Comment: @Taryn - I use these all the time, but the problem with them is that they aren't cheap. The output time of the overall query increases greatly depending on the volume of data in the stuffed sub query. Honestly hoping for a better way that isn't as costly.