# Why am I not getting a distinct grouping here?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT "STORE VISIT",STORE,USERVISITED 
FROM ECRSURVEY 
WHERE "STORE VISIT" > '2014-01-01     00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY STORE, "STORE VISIT", UserVisited
```

Shouldn't this return a distinct grouping of the column STORE? My result is multiple entries of the same STORE.

Comment: You're getting unique *combinations* of `STORE, "STORE VISIT", UserVisited`.

Comment: What is `UserVisited`?

Comment: Change the `group by` to `group by store`.

Comment: Can you give us a query to create your table and also insert a few sample rows into it ? Also, what is your excpected output ?

Comment: You may want to look into how [Group By](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get distinct `STORE`:

```
SELECT STORE 
FROM   ECRSURVEY 
WHERE  "STORE VISIT" > '20140101'
GROUP BY STORE
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT STORE 
FROM   ECRSURVEY 
WHERE  "STORE VISIT" > '20140101'
```

or

if you do aggregates of the other two fields then you should get unique rows

```
SELECT STORE 
       NumStoreVisit = COUNT("STORE VISIT"), 
       NumUserVisited = COUNT(UserVisited)
FROM   ECRSURVEY 
WHERE  "STORE VISIT" > '20140101'
GROUP BY STORE
```

but if your data is structured like the following then you are asking for the impossible:

[image]

Comment: If I do this I cant get the data for the other two columns that I need. Only the store column is returned. I need all three.

Comment: If I try to only group by store, I receive an error because the other two fields are not in the group by clause.

Comment: are you multiple rows returned totally identical? or do they have different values in "STORE VISIT" & USERVISITED ?

Comment: whytheq is right with his options when trying to get a distinct store. If you are trying to get a distinct store, with data as shown in whytheq's impossible table, do you want the other values to be comma separated perhaps? If yes, have a look at the answer in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235693/comma-delimited-list-as-a-single-string-t-sql