# Using For XML + STUFF to achieve a STRAGG-like functionality multiple times for the same selection

Tags: sql-server

[**I've seen**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235693/comma-delimited-list-as-a-single-string-t-sql/18235816#18235816) people combining both `FOR XML` and `STUFF` statements to achieve a `STRAGG`-like in Sql Server.

I have a problem with this approach in that, given I have a couple of fields I want to aggregate into strings to the outermost query, I am repeating the same select statement over and over again, for each new aggregation.

As far as I understand, however, this `FOR XML` + `STUFF` solution has to be applied in the innermost level - meaning I can't add an inline view with the select statement I will be using in the aggregations and apply `Distinct` on it, because I will already have joined the results with each of the distinct values.

In a short, adding to the example taken from the site cited above, here's what I want to do:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84199/2/0

Is there any better solution when you want to do that for a number of aggregations, so to avoid such redundant performance penalties ?

Comment: What do you mean by better (shorter)? Using Oracle `LISTAGG` or MySQL `GROUP_CONCAT` you have to specify them for each concated column. SqlServer has this workaround with `FOR XML and STUFF` and it needs to be repeated.

Comment: That's what I wanted to avoid - having to repeat the same Selection over and over again, in Sql Server

Comment: It isn't shorter but you can use [this syntax](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84199/15/0)

Comment: @lad2025: where is the gain ? I will do the same cross apply twice

Comment: There isn't any gain in length, but your select is clearer, I doubt you find more concise approach. Read [Concatenating Row Values in Transact-SQL](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)

Comment: That's why I posted the question... thanks for helping, anyway. By the way, when I say "gain" I mean in performance.

Comment: If you found shorter solution without Dynamic-SQL please let me know.