# STRING_AGG is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I've downloaded and installed SQL Server 2016. When I attempted to use the `STRING_AGG` function I receive this error. Here is my code:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(cast(FieldNumber AS VARCHAR(100)), ',')
FROM Fields
```

I've installed SQL Server 2016 and SP1. Is there anything else I need to do. Here is the feature I am trying to use. [String Agg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt790580.aspx)

Comment: When you need to aggregate lists to strings in pre-"STRING_ADD" SQL Server versions, check out the `FOR XML` or `FOR JSON` statements, which can be put on **subqueries**.  They do not provide the exact functionality, put are still powerful tools.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`STRING_AGG` is not introduced in `SQL SERVER 2016`.

It is introduced in `SQL SERVER 2017`. In the MSDN [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt790580.aspx) you have provided it is mentioned ***THIS TOPIC APPLIES TO : SQL Server 2017*** not `SQL SERVER 2016`.

At the time of the question, this version was known by the code name "vNext", described as:

> SQL Server vNext represents a major step towards making SQL Server a
> platform that enables choices of development languages, data types,
> on-premises and in the cloud, and across operating systems by bringing
> the power of SQL Server to Linux, Linux-based Docker containers, and
> Windows. SQL Server vNext also includes the features added in SQL Server 2016 service packs

Comment: `vNext` was only a project name during development. `STRING_AGG` was made publicly available as of `SQL Server 2017`.

Comment: *sigh*.........

Comment: btw postgres had arrays in 2001

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to [comma delimited list as a single string, T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235693/comma-delimited-list-as-a-single-string-t-sql).
There are instructions how to use STUFF function to construct such a list.

Answer (score 0):

You might have multiple SQL server instances installed for various SQL versions.
Go to the Services and start the service for newly installed SQL server version instance.

Then connect that instance with your SQL server management studio.