# Function string_agg does not work in SMSS 17

Tags: sql, ssms

This is my data:

[image]

Im trying the following code:

```
SELECT *,
        STRING_AGG(SUBTIPO_PRODUCTO, ' | ')
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ORDEN_PRODUCTOS) PRODUCTOS
FROM #ORDEN_PRODUCTOS
```

and I'm getting the following error:

> 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Is `string_agg` locked for SMSS 17? Is the code wrong?

Comment: Run `SELECT @@VERSION` in SSMS and tell us what version it says you are using.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923080/string-agg-is-not-a-recognized-built-in-function-name

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2) (KB4052908) - 13.0.5026.0 (X64)   Mar 18 2018 09:11:49   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: `STRING_AGG` is only available in SQL Server **2017** or newer - not in 2016..... and it only depends on the **server** (engine) version - not the SSMS version you're using .

Answer (score 1):

The available functions in SQL Server are determined by the compatibility setting of the database, which is a representation of the version of SQL Server that the database is currently running on. If you are using SQL Server 2014 as a server, SSMS 2017 doesn't grant the `STRING_AGG` function. You need to be working in SQL Server 2017 or higher for `STRING_AGG` to work.

Comment: This isn't 100% correct I believe. If you have a 2017 install/instance, make a DB with 2012 compatibility level, you can still run things like ISJSON which is only available in 2016 and later.

Comment: Hm, I'll have to double check that - I know that when I was using my 2017 instance with a 2012 compatibility, STRING_AGG failed to execute (I had to set compatibility lower after I had written some code, for a class) -- I suppose I can't speak to every function.

Comment: I believe this is not accurate since my SQL Server is 2016: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2) (KB4052908) - 13.0.5026.0 (X64)   Mar 18 2018 09:11:49   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Hi Ivancito, as I stated in my original answer and was commented on your initial post, `STRING_AGG` requires SQL Server 2017 and you do not have it.