# SQL Query resultset output as a single row using comma

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these 3 tables as below.

```
    Table: Student
        -------------
        |  ID | Name| 
        +-----+-----+
        | S01 |Alex |
        | S02 |Sam  |
        | S03 |May  |
        -------------

    Table: Book
        --------------
        |  ID | Name | 
        +-----+------+
        | B01 |BookA |
        | B02 |BookB |
        | B03 |BookC |
        --------------

    Table:StudentBooks
        --------------
        |  SID| BID  | 
        +-----+------+
        | S01 |B01   |
        | S02 |B02   |
        | S01 |B03   |
        | S02 |B03   |
        --------------
```

**Here is the output I want to get.**

```
    -----------------------
    |  Name |     Book    | 
    +-------+-------------+
    | Alex  |BookA, Book C|
    | Sam   |BookB, Book C|
    | May   |             |
    -----------------------
```

I tried with the following code, but it seems not able to get the correct book name based on the student name. My current output is that all the books are shown in every row, including student named 'May' which not allocated with any books.

```
SELECT s.Name AS Name,
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + b.Name
              FROM StudentBook sb
                   JOIN Student s ON s.ID = sb.SID
                   JOIN Book b ON b.ID = sb.BID
              WHERE s.Name = s.Name
             FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS Book
FROM StudentBooks sb
     JOIN Book b ON b.ID = sb.BID
     JOIN Student s ON s.ID = sb.SID;
```

Comment: `WHERE s.Name = s.Name`? When is the value of `s.Name` not going to be the value of `s.Name` (apart from when it's `NULL`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner & outer references are not matching. You are referencing student name to book :

```
SELECT s.Name AS Name,
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + b.Name
              FROM StudentBook sb JOIN 
                   Book b 
                   ON b.ID = sb.BID
              WHERE sb.sid = s.id
              FOR XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
             ) AS Book
FROM Student s;
```

Comment: I tried with this but I'm still getting all the books for every students.. Even student name 'May' who is not allocated with any books.

Comment: @newlearner. . . This does what you want with `May` who doesn't have any books.

Comment: yes it works! sorry I missed out  Where statement. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

STRING_AGG will also solve the problem

```
SELECT  S.[Name],
    STRING_AGG(B.[Name], ', ') AS Books
FROM StudentBooks AS SB WITH(NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN Student AS S WITH(NOLOCK) ON S.ID = SB.SID
    INNER JOIN Book AS B WITH(NOLOCK) ON B.ID = SB.BID
GROUP BY S.[Name]
```

Comment: its having error :'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: I saw "sql-server" was tagged, is this not what you are using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923080/string-agg-is-not-a-recognized-built-in-function-name