# TSQL FOR JSON nested value

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to output JSON via tsql hierarchy table.

Code:

```
select Field1, Field2 from @header inner join @line on @header.Id = @Line.Id FOR JSON AUTO
```

I am getting:

```
"Field1": "BOB",
"Field2": "BOB2",
```

but I am looking for it to display

```
 "Field1": {
   "value": "BOB"
 },
 "Field2": {
   "value": "BOB2"
 },
```

What am I doing wrong?  I can using text manipulation, but was wondering if there is a "blessed" way, i.e. built-in that is readable and best-practice.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Version 2016 SP2

Comment: Only with some string manipulation or even worse some dynamic SQL,   That said, it seems like an odd structure to me  ...  Question: how would multiple records be presented

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I only have a single record example from the customer - who wants data back.  Conceivably, I could send single records anyway - sort of individual order line updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Select STRING_AGG(concat('"',[Key],'":{"value":"',string_escape(Value,'json'),'"}'),',')
  From  OpenJson(  (Select * From @YourTable For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper ) )
```

**For 2016 -- STUFF XML**

```
Select stuff((Select concat('"',[Key],'":{"value":"',string_escape(Value,'json'),'"}') 
  From  OpenJson(  (Select * From @YourTable For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper ) )
  For XML Path ('')),1,0,'')
```

**Results**

```
"Field1":{
   "value":"Bob"
 },
"Field2":{
    "value":"Bob2"
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the `STRING_ESCAPE` when cobbling together JSON like this. Today it's Bob, tomorrow it's Newline Bob. (The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/string-escape-transact-sql#b-format-json-object) actually have an interesting example of using `FORMATMESSAGE` for these purposes.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Valid point.   Updated  and added the stuff/XML approach as well

Comment: You read my mind., I was busing converting and testing on STUFF.. Some docs suggest STRING_AGG is 2016, but it isn't.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40923548/1662973

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a path for each column name, combined with `FOR JSON PATH`.

```sql
SELECT
  Field1 AS [Field1.value],
  Field2 AS [Field2.value]
FROM @header h
JOIN @line l ON h.Id = l.Id
FOR JSON PATH;
```

If you need the two fields as entirely separate rows each with its own object, you can unpivot it

```sql
SELECT
  v.[Field1.value],
  v.[Field2.value]
FROM @header h
JOIN @line l ON h.Id = l.Id
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    (Field1, NULL),
    (NULL, Field2)
) v([Field1.value], [Field2.value])
FOR JSON PATH;
```

Comment: This also really helped me!  Combined with https://database.guide/sql-server-for-json-path-examples-t-sql/ to get the hierarchy.